# How to fetch data from Firebase in getServerSideProps with NextJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-admin

I am trying to figure out how to fetch data from Firebase inside GetServerSideProps in NextJs

Here is my db file

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import serviceAccount from "./serviceAccountKey.json";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  try {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Firebase admin initialization error", error.stack);
  }
}
export default admin.firestore();
```

Then inside getServerSideProps

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const id = context.params.profileId;
  const doc = await db.collection("profile").doc(id).get();
  const profile = doc.data();
  return {
    props: { profile },
  };
}
```

Getting the following error

```
error - ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:21:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Is there another way to call firebase without using the Node Library that relies on the filesystem? Or is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: you are gettng that error because somewhere in client side you are using firebase code which belongs to server-side. In client-side you have no `fs` module so the code that running on client is failing

Comment: That seems to be the case. However according to Next.js Documentation, getServerSideProps only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `firebase-admin`, you can use only in api functions. you cannot even import it on the client side. It needs to access to `fs` module which is not available on client side. If you need firebase in client side use [@firebase/app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app) npm module.

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics'
export const createFirebaseApp = () => {
  const clientCredentials = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  }

  if (getApps().length <= 0) {
    const app = initializeApp(clientCredentials)
    // Check that `window` is in scope for the analytics module!
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      // Enable analytics. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started
      if ('measurementId' in clientCredentials) {
        getAnalytics()
      }
    }
    return app
  }
}
```

you can have two separate [firebase config files](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase/firebase). One for client side as above, another one is using `firebase-admin` as you defined

Comment: Nice! This works.